Sending Message to RabbitMQ using HTTP API
Is there a way to send a message directly in the RabbitMQ publish API with only the message itself?
/api/exchanges/%2f/amq.default/publish
Without putting the message in the payload object and not adding the other object params such as the routing_key etc?
I tried in my queue and exchange I just set some arguments, with
x-match = all and all other arguments, thinking that this might be the solution
and on the request added the argument parameters but still getting
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"[{key_missing,routing_key},\n {key_missing,properties},\n {key_missing,payload},\n {key_missing,payload_encoding}]"}
Is there a way to bypass this?
